# How to make all action bar items white?

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar, android-theme, android-styles

I cannot use `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` because of [this HTC bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78819).

So I've been trying to find a workaround. I attempted to remove the `DarkActionBar` and just use `Theme.AppCompat.Light` as a parent of my app theme; it fixed the bug, but some items in my action bar appear black:

[image: Black searchview sign, back button, overflow icon]
[image: Black search text and clear button]
[image: Black Drawer-arrow-toggle and menu item text]

Items that appear black: v7 ActionBarDrawerToggle, SearchView controls, SearchView text, overflow menu icon, menu item text.

Is there a way to make them all white?

Answer (score 0):

Use Toolbar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/blue"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/actionbar_height"/>
```

And add this on style and manifest:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/light_gray</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@color/white</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>

</style>
```